# Upload backgorund image in canvas FabricJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

How can I upload background image in FabricJS Canvas from local using input type file.

I have code for images can I use this code also for background image:

```
var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);

    function handleImage(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(img, {
                    scaleX: 0.5,
                    scaleY: 0.5
                })

                canvas.add(imgInstance);
            }
            img.src = event.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
```

See: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/anj9uj77/13/)

Comment: Try this: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage

Comment: Also, this answer might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17231604/3345375

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but only after loading the image. You have to load it `fromURL` and after that, place it as the background:

```js
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener("change", function(e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(f) {
      var data = f.target.result;
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
         // add background image
         canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
            scaleX: canvas.width / img.width,
            scaleY: canvas.height / img.height
         });
      });
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```